# Yii app session assign issue

Tags: php, session, yii

I am trying to assign a session value like this

```
Yii::app()->session['searchData']['per_page'] = $per_page;
```

But i got an error "Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect"

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this to set session variables

```
 Yii::app()->user->setState('searchData_perPage',$per_page);
```

Retrive the same by using

```
 Yii::app()->user->getState('searchData_perPage');
```

Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail for more info

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::app()->session` is an object not like `$_SESSION` which is an array. You cannot use it this way. Try:

```
Yii::app()->session['searchData'] = array('per_page', $per_page);
```